# Rotational Averaging of Image Periodograms (FFTS)

Tags: image-processing, mathematical-optimization, fourier-analysis

I'm writing a code to do rotational averages of image FFT's. I have a working version but it is pretty slow. Wondering if anyone has any thoughts on a way to do this more efficiently.

Data looks like this generally:

[image: rawData FFT]

```
    img1 = Import["http://i.imgur.com/0QZs0AN.png"];
    img = ImageAdjust[ImagePeriodogram[img1], 1];

    imgpts[r_, \[CapitalDelta]_, imagedimension_] := 
      If[r != 0 , Table[{r Cos[2 \[Pi] t] + imagedimension/2, 
    r Sin[2 \[Pi] t] 
    + imagedimension/2} // N, {t, 0, 1, 
    1/(\[CapitalDelta] r)}], {{imagedimension/2, imagedimension/2},
    {imagedimension/2, imagedimension/2}} // N];

    RotationalAverage[FFT_, imgdim_, rmax_, \[CapitalDelta]_, inter_] := 
      Table[{r, Mean[ImageValue[FFT, #, Resampling -> inter] & /@ 
      imgpts[r, \[CapitalDelta], imgdim]]}, {r, 0, rmax}];

    imagevals = RotationalAverage[img, 1024, 140, 16, "Bicubic"];
```

I decided to make each circle average over bins of the same arc-length. Im not sure if this is the "right" way to do this, but it seemed like a good idea.
This gets me the data I want and I usually make a plot at this point just to check.

```
    ListPlot[imagevals]
```

[image: plot for checking]

Then i stitch the images together to get a picture.

```
    ImgData = Reverse@Table[If[N[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] < 140,         
    Interpolation[imagevals][Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] // N], 0], {x, 0, 128}, 
    {y, 0, 128}] // Quiet;

    ImageAdjust[ImageAssemble[{{Image[Reverse@Transpose@ImgData], 
    Image[ImgData]}, {Image[Transpose@ImgData],Image[Reverse@ImgData]}}], 1]
```

To get something like this

[image: final product]

What I'm ultimately after i guess is some optimization of accurate and fast, which is pretty vague but i guess i don't know how else to say it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can transform the image into polar coordinates, after which averaging across angles is trivial.

```
polarTransform[img_, rmax_] := 
 With[{size = Max@ImageDimensions[img]}, 
  ImageTransformation[img, 
   Function[{r, t}, {r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}] @@ # &, {rmax + 1, 2 Pi rmax}, 
   DataRange -> {{-size/2, size/2}, {-size/2, size/2}}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1/2, rmax + 1/2}, {0, 2 Pi}}, Resampling -> "Bicubic"]]
rmax = 140;
polarImg = polarTransform[img, rmax];
imageVals = Mean /@ Transpose@ImageData@polarImg;
ListPlot[imageVals, DataRange -> {0, rmax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

On my machine, this runs about 20 times faster than the corresponding part of your code, probably because `ImageTransformation` is a highly optimized internal function. Maybe you'd get similar performance if you `Compile`'d your code?

Anyway, heck, now we can use `ImageTransformation` again to create the rotationally averaged image.

```
w = 128;
ImageTransformation[Image[{imageVals}], {Norm[#], 0} &, {2 w + 1, 2 w + 1}, 
 DataRange -> {{-1/2, rmax + 1/2}, {0, 2 Pi}},
 PlotRange -> {{-w - 1/2, w + 1/2}, {-w - 1/2, w + 1/2}}, Resampling -> "Bicubic"]
```

[image]

All the $+\frac12$'s and $-\frac12$'s in the `DataRange` and `PlotRange` are so that the pixels themselves lie at integer coordinates; see [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42825/484) and compare the documentation for [`ImageValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageValue.html) and [`PixelValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PixelValue.html). So, for example, by setting the range of $r$ to be $\{-1/2, r_\max + 1/2\}$ in the first `ImageTransformation`, we get samples at $r = 0, 1, ..., r_\max$ instead of $\frac12, 1\!\frac12, ..., r_\max - \frac12$.

Comment: @RahulNarian I've been looking at this for a while and comparing it to my code. One thing that is bothering me is [this plot](http://i.imgur.com/cWZZigt.jpg) of the difference between the methods as a function of radius. There seems to be some sort of systematic effect at small radii that I don't understand.

Comment: @bshev: Good catch! My previous code was off by half a pixel. Please see the updated answer. There is much less of a difference with your results now.

Answer (score 7):

How about using nesting [`ImageRotate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageRotate.html):

```
t = NestList[ImageRotate[#, 5 Degree, Full] &, img, 71];
ImageData /@ t;
out = Total[%] // Image // ImageAdjust
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Extracting a line looks similar to yours

```
idata = ImageData[out];
ListPlot[idata[[All, 512]], PlotRange -> {{512, 652}, {0.4, 1}}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Not sure this is faster than the method in the question.

Comment: @RahulNarain I agree I haven't tested it, but I am also performing the operation on the entire image, and from what I gather in the OP's code, only the data ~140 pixels from the center are being analyzed.