# How to get the mean color of an artwork?

Tags: graphics

I got [a piece of artwork](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZWEu.jpg) in dimension of 20x20 pixels. I attempted to divide it into a 5x5 array of elements each of a smaller size of 4x4 pixels, and would like to find the mean color of the elements. I got the job done in a double for-loop. Is there a better way to do it? I need a faster way to treat much larger pieces.

[image]

```
Clear[avg]
avg = ConstantArray[0, {5, 5}];
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZWEu.jpg"] ;
idata = ImageData[image];
ddata = Partition[idata , {4, 4}, 4] ;
For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= 5, j++,
  avg[[i, j]] = Mean@Flatten[ddata[[i, j]], 1 ];
  ]]
Image[avg]
```

This is what I got:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve this:

```
img = Import["file.jpg"];
data = ImageData[img];
```

Then:

```
Image @ Developer`PartitionMap[Mean[Flatten[#, 1]] &, data, {4, 4}, 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice, I did not know about `PartitionMap`. That's super useful.

Comment: @mfvonh, I know. It's a gem I use often :)

Answer (score 8):

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZWEu.jpg"]
ImagePartition[image, {4, 4}] /. i_Image :> MeanFilter[i, 4] // ImageAssemble
```

[image]

**EDIT**

For comparison:

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZWEu.jpg"];
ImageData[image];
rk = Image@Developer`PartitionMap[Mean[Flatten[#, 1]] &, %, {4, 4}, 4]
mf = ImagePartition[image, {4, 4}] /. i_Image :> MeanFilter[i, 4] // ImageAssemble
mw = ImageResize[image, Scaled[1/4], Resampling -> "Linear"]
{rk, mf, mw} = Show[#, ImageSize -> 200] & /@ ImageResize[#, 200] & /@ {rk, mf, mw}
ColorNegate /@ ImageSubtract @@@ Subsets[%, {2}]
ImageAdjust /@ %;
Transpose[{%%, %}] // GraphicsGrid
```

Rows are: rk-mf, rk-mw, mf-mw

[image]

Comment: The values produced by this method are also not exact as `MeanFilter` does not take a complete average of the image.  Also, the "pixels" are really 4x4 sections.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I wouldn't have picked up on that.

Comment: Clearly your result is closer to the OP's original, apart from the 4x4 "pixel" thing.

Comment: Closer-ish -- there appear to be problems on the boundaries as you alluded to. And it's slow :)

Answer (score 8):

What you describe is nearly a linear downsampling of the image as achieved with [`ImageResize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageResize.html):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZWEu.jpg"]

ImageResize[img, Scaled[1/4], Resampling -> "Linear"]
```

[image]

The values are not exact, presumably due to a different alignment of the resampling grid but I have not found a way to adjust that in this function.

Comment: I'm not sure, but my guess would be that the edge values surrounding a grid cell have some weight in the resampled mean value. There is, I believe, a theoretical reason for preferring this approach (at least for photographs) -- maybe one of our image experts will comment. Another strong reason is that `ImageResize` is quite a bit faster than the other current answers. (+1 of course.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Would you say that [(42825)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42825) explains this issue, at least pragmatically?

Comment: It seems to explain upsampling.  Downsampling seems different.